# Can't get CSS drop down nav to go over content only on home page

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have issues with the menu only on the home page.

When I hover on the category "Replacement Parts", the drop down menu perfectly goes over the slider but not over the text content. I can't figure out how to fix with CSS.

Please help!

https://www.trampolineandparts.co.uk/

Thank you

Comment: Did my answer help at all???

Comment: Hello! It worked!!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Cool. Please consider marking the answer as accepted by hitting the ✓ symbol or the upvote ^ button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the following:

```
body.cms-home .main-container {
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 10000;  /*remove this*/
}
```

The `z-index` of your `main-container` sets it's stack order to be higher than that of your dropdown menu.

At a glance, it doesn't look like you need to defined a `z-index` here. So go ahead and remove it.

It also seems like you're using `z-index` a lot in your code. Not sure why that is - you typically don't need to change it unless you're dealing with complex layouts.

Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) or on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp):

> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
>
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.
>
> **Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Also, perhaps you should look into using a framework as this would make managing your layout easier for you. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), for example. Good luck.